# QT Creator - Testing Code

Tags: application-development

I am doing the tutorial 'CurrencyConverter'. But I am not able to see the output.
The code compiles fine. But the mainview after opening just shows blank window.
What might be the issue?

Comment: perhaps you didnt copy the code code correctly? You dont really provide any information to allow us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the code with :
`bzr branch lp:ubuntu-sdk-tutorials` and then follow the tutorial trying to understand your errors.

[Develop page 4 Tutorial Currency Converter](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/4/)